# Checkable Contact List in Android

Tags: android, preference

I want to make a checkable Contact List that should be stored by the application, allow the users to place checks on some contacts, and store users' preferences.
I want to know whether a preference activity can be used to list all contacts as checkboxes, 
or whether a custom listview can allow me to save the users preferences for the app?

Comment: and what you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

you can get contact data with following code:

```
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
                        null, null);

                cursor.moveToFirst();

                if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                    do {

                        try {
                            contactId = cursor
                                    .getString(cursor
                                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

                            Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                                    Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                                    Long.parseLong(contactId));
                            Uri dataUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri,
                                    Contacts.Data.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);

                            Cursor phones = getContentResolver()
                                    .query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                            null,
                                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                                    + " = " + contactId,
                                            null, null);
                            if (phones.getCount() > 0) {

                                try {
                                    Cursor nameCursor = getContentResolver()
                                            .query(dataUri,
                                                    null,
                                                    Data.MIMETYPE + "=?",
                                                    new String[] { StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE },
                                                    null);
                                    nameCursor.moveToFirst();
                                    do {

                                        String firstName = nameCursor
                                                .getString(nameCursor
                                                        .getColumnIndex(Data.DATA2));

                                        String displayname = cursor
                                                .getString(cursor
                                                        .getColumnIndex(Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_ALTERNATIVE));

                                        lastName = nameCursor
                                                .getString(nameCursor
                                                        .getColumnIndex(Data.DATA3));

                                    } while (nameCursor.moveToNext());
                                    nameCursor.close();

                                } catch (Exception e) {

                                }
                            }
                            phones.close();
                        }

                        catch (Exception t) {

                        }

                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());

                   }
```

after get list of your contact name or anything that you want you need create custom adapter to show this data, for creating the custom list see this [link](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) and [this](http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92).

//////////////////////

EDIT:

you can get phone number with following code:

```
    String number = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
```

Comment: Thanx Shayan Pourvatan,But is it possible for me to give the array of contacts to a listpreference where the user can check some contacts.And if this is not possible can i easily store the contacts the users checks from the custom adapter for the listview in a form of users preferences.

Comment: yes, easily you can add `display name` or `firstname + lastname` to one list and set to adapter, and when user check the contact get the name and what every thing you want. but for create custom adapter see the link, that useful for you

Comment: if you think my answer is right mark as answer that other people that have a same problem can use that